Bulk edit elementor pages to remove/edit something (container/widget)
I'm trying to create a custom function in WordPress to remove in bulk a specific Elementor containder with specific ID from all pages that use it(because it was inserted manually on hundreds of pages).
when I use this code with json_decode/json_encode the posts are updated by deleting the desired element but then it seems that the pages have bugs and are not displayed correctly (graphics), I think it is due to the fact that Elementor uses specific functions.
function bulk_remove_elementor_widget_with_log() {
    $log = '';

    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'meta_key' => '_elementor_data',
        'post_status' => 'publish', 
        'numberposts' => -1,
    ));

    if (empty($posts)) {
        return "Not found.";
    }

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $log .= "Processing post ID: " . $post->ID . " - " . $post->post_title . "\n";
        
        $result = remove_elementor_widget_by_id_with_log($post->ID);
        
        if ($result) {
            $log .= "Element post ID: " . $post->ID . "\n";
        } else {
            $log .= "Element post ID: " . $post->ID . "\n";
        }
    }

    return $log;
}

if (!function_exists('search_and_remove_widget')) {

    function search_and_remove_widget($elements, &$found) {
        foreach ($elements as $key => &$element) {

    if (isset($element['id']) && $element['id'] === '4132e9d6') {
                unset($elements[$key]);
                $found = true;
            }
            if (isset($element['elements'])) {
                $element['elements'] = search_and_remove_widget($element['elements'], $found);
            }
        }
        return $elements;
    }
}

function remove_elementor_widget_by_id_with_log($post_id) {
    $elementor_data = get_post_meta($post_id, '_elementor_data', true);

    $elementor_data = json_decode($elementor_data, true);

    $found = false;

    $new_elementor_data = search_and_remove_widget($elementor_data, $found);

    if ($found) {
        $new_elementor_data = json_encode($new_elementor_data);

        update_post_meta($post_id, '_elementor_data', $new_elementor_data);
    }

    return $found;
}

Can you help me understand which functions to use
